# iOS App - implement offline caching for limited time using "max-stale" along with URLRequest's 'returnCacheDataDontLoad' CachePolicy

Tags: ios, swift, http, caching, urlsession

We have a requirement to hit the WebRequest each time when online, but used cached response for upto 4 hours when device is offline.

When the device is offline, we are changing the URLRequest's CachePolicy to '.returnCacheDataDontLoad'
Please find relevant code below,

```
if isOffline && request.isOfflineCompatible {
    urlRequest.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataDontLoad
    urlRequest.setValue("max-stale=14400", forHTTPHeaderField: "cache-control")
} else {
    // Assigning the cache policy back to the one set while creating request
    //default is useProtocolCachePolicy
    urlRequest.cachePolicy = request.cachePolicy
}
```

**Irrespective of the 'max-stale' value assigned, the request returns success each time in spite of the anticipated failure post the 'max-stale' duration. Similar implementation works fine on Android.**

**Print description of the offline request object:**

> - url : Optional some : (confidential api url)
> - cachePolicy : 3
> - timeoutInterval : 30.0
> - mainDocumentURL : nil
> - networkServiceType : __C.NSURLRequestNetworkServiceType
> - allowsCellularAccess : true
> - httpMethod : Optional some : "GET"
> - allHTTPHeaderFields : Optional<Dictionary<String, String>>3 elements
>
>   - key : "Cache-Control"
>   - value : "max-stale=120" (lower value for testing convenience)
>   - key : "Content-Type"
>   - value : "application/json"
>   - key : "APIKey"
>   - value : "abcdxyz"
> - httpBody : nil
> - httpBodyStream : nil
> - httpShouldHandleCookies : true
> - httpShouldUsePipelining : false

**Print description of the respective response**

> <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x281dc61a0> { URL: confidential } { Status Code:
> 200, Headers {
> "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =     (
> "*"
> );
> "Cache-Control" =     (
> "max-age=30"
> );
> "Content-Encoding" =     (
> gzip
> );
> "Content-Length" =     (
> 9797
> );
> "Content-Type" =     (
> "application/json"
> );
> Date =     (
> "Sun, 16 Apr 2023 18:33:23 GMT"
> );
> Etag =     (
> 0x8DB33C6C0E756AD
> );
> Expires =     (
> "Sun, 16 Apr 2023 18:33:53 GMT"
> );
> "Last-Modified" =     (
> "Sun, 02 Apr 2023 22:08:13 GMT"
> );
> Vary =     (
> "Accept-Encoding"
> );
> "content-md5" =     (
> "ozV+j+j89923XIxSCSjFoA=="
> );
> "request-context" =     (
> "appId=cid-v1:79144720-54fb-43e6-964e-37c4f997a8ec"
> );
> "x-ms-blob-type" =     (
> BlockBlob
> );
> "x-ms-lease-status" =     (
> unlocked
> );
> "x-ms-request-id" =     (
> "154aae09-301e-004e-201f-6e69d9000000"
> );
> "x-ms-version" =     (
> "2009-09-19"
> ); } }

Comment: So you have `max-age=30`. The `max-stale` starts only after `max-age` ends. So total you need to wait 30 (max-age) + 120 (max-stale). Did you wait that long?

Comment: Yeah I did wait significantly longer than 150 seconds.